# Prestashop removing empty link widget divs

Tags: php, prestashop

I added **link widget blocks** to try my **Prestashop 1.7** web site. After the try, I removed the link widget blocks. But there are **empty divs** on the site. How do I remove these empty divs?
Thanks...

[image: Visual description of my problem]

Comment: what do you mean by "removed"? Did you completely uninstall the module?

Comment: No, I delete my changes. Only the default footer block was left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link widget module adds hooks to the positions page. On the **positions** page in admin panel I unhook the link lists hooks in **displayNav2** position.

Answer (score 0):

the divs are located in this file on the classic theme Prestashop 1.7 :

```
themes/classic/modules/ps_linklist/views/templates/hook/linkblock.tpl
```

Comment: This is the general design of the link widget blocks. When I make changes to this file, the design of the footer link widgets is disrupted. Also I want to use link blocks in footer.
Problem: After removing link widget blocks, empty link widget block divs remain in the design. 
Thanks.